# Solving $ \mathcal{L}(\sin({\omega t+a})) $ using properties of Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

I know this can be solved easily be expanding as follows,
$$ \mathcal{L}(\sin{(\omega t + a)}) = \mathcal{L}(\sin{\omega t} \cos{a} + \sin{a} \cos{\omega t}) $$
which  is very simple after this.

But I want to know if it can be solved using properties of Laplace transform, i.e. time shift and scaling. For e.g. 
 $$ \mathcal{L}(e^{-at}\sin{bt}) = \frac{b^2}{(s+a)^2 + b^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think this work 
$$\sin(\omega t+a) = \dfrac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i(\omega t+a)}-e^{-i(\omega t+a)}\right) = \dfrac{e^{ia}}{2i}e^{i\omega t}-\dfrac{e^{-ia}}{2i}e^{-i\omega t}$$

Comment: This is correct, I get the same transform results. Why does the following not work?
$$\mathcal{L}(\sin{(\omega(t+\frac{a}{\omega}))})$$
And apply time shift property, followed by scaling?

Comment: I think this works also, but you need add unit step function to get the result and be care about the region of laplace existance.

Comment: okay, I think I understood what goes wrong if I blindly apply the property here. The scaling property is on the variable $(t+\frac{a}{\omega})$ but the time shift is on the variable $t$, and I want to transform in terms of $t$, so I cannot do it blindly. Am I right?

Comment: Yes I think....